# SiteLock implementation for trusted site zone

Tags: c++, security, internet-explorer, activex, trusted-sites

I have added SiteLock 1.15 mechanism to my ActiveX - I want to restrict loading and running ActiveX from sites that are not in "Trusted Sites Zone".

I have added the following map:

```
const struct IObjectSafetySiteLock::SiteList MyClass::rgslTrustedSites[2] =
{
 { SiteList::Allow, L"http", SITELOCK_TRUSTED_ZONE },
 { SiteList::Allow, L"https", SITELOCK_TRUSTED_ZONE }
};
```

But when I run sitelist.exe provided with SiteLock 1.15 SDK,

I'm getting:

```
Version: 1.21
Features:  Uses IOleObject instead of IObjectWithSite
  Allow http://(All Sites in Intranet Zone)
  Allow https://(All Sites in Intranet Zone)
```

Shouldn't I get "All sites in Trusted Sites Zone ?

Thanks

Comment: When I have verified the ActiveX, it worked fine for trusted sites and was blocked in intranet zone.